# Django CSV Import - Only importing first data row when using æ, ø ,å (danish characters) and spaces

Tags: python, mysql, django, csv, django-views

I have made a system in Django with a CSV import implementation. However when the first column of the data contains danish special characters Æ, Ø and Å or spaces it only inserts the first data row.

I read that the csv module in Python that I'm using does not support Unicode input. I have provided the code below for the function that connects the csv file with Database Model in Django.

Note: Database is made in Mysql

**views.py**

```
def opret_hold(request):
    prompt = {
        "hold": "Rækkefølgen på inholdet af din .csv fil skal være: ma, fornavn, efternavn, hold, deling"
    }

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'evalsys/admin/upload/opret_hold.html', prompt)
    try:
        csv_file = request.FILES['file']

        if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
            messages.warning(request, 'Dette er ikke en .csv fil.')

        data_set = csv_file.read().decode("utf-8")
        io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
        for row in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=','):
            for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=','):
                __, created = Hold.objects.get_or_create(
                    holdnavn=column[0],
                    slug=column[0],
                )
                created = Medarbejder.objects.get_or_create(
                    delingnavn_id=column[1],
                    slug=column[2],
                    ma=column[2],
                    fornavn=column[3],
                    efternavn=column[4],
                    holdnavn_id=Hold.objects.get(pk=(column[0])),
                )

        if request.method == 'POST' and HttpResponse.status_code == 200:
            messages.success(request, "Hold oprettet.")

    finally:
        context = {}
        return render(request, 'evalsys/admin/upload/opret_hold.html', context)
```

**opret_hold.html**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="file" name="file" required>
                        <p>Dette system acceptere kun .csv filer.</p>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn" id="generel-btn">Upload</button>
                        <br>
                    </form>
```

Comment: If you are using Linux you could try the "iconv" command before the data gets imported into mysql. Maybe you can implement iconv somewhere in your python scripts. I had a similar problem (not python but perl) when i uploaded csv and json db-import files from windows to linux. I had to convert to latin1 for the German Umlaute to be recognized in MongoDB and MySQL.

Comment: You could make a copy of your csv import file, convert it with iconv to (latin1) like this: iconv -f <<yourcharcoding>> -t latin1 and then import the converted file into a mysql test database. If the danish characters are recognized and the import works, you could call a method in your views.py that executes the iconv command before the csv file gets imported into mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in your for loop you wrote 2 loops which indirectly access only rows

```
data_set = csv_file.read().decode("utf-8")
io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
for row in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=','):
   hold, created = Hold.objects.get_or_create(
    holdnavn=row[0],
    slug=row[0],
   )
   medarbejder,created = Medarbejder.objects.get_or_create(
    delingnavn_id=row[1],
    slug=row[2],
    ma=row[2],
    fornavn=row[3],
    efternavn=row[4],
    holdnavn_id=hold,
   )
```

Comment: When I only have one loop nothing happens but when I have two loops I am able to get some data into the database from the file, as long as the data in the first column "holdnavn" does not contain Æ, Ø, Å or spaces.
I tried with your suggestion and it didn't work